# Application failed codesign verification annoying error!

Tags: xcode, application-loader

I have looked at so many posts about this but nothing helps. It is the error in application loader and in xcode:

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Comment: Somebody already asked this question on SO. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879473/how-to-fix-failed-codesign-verification-of-an-iphone-project):

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes of the -19011 code verification error (as evidenced by the [dozens of near identical stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22failed%20codesign%22%20%22-19011%22) about it). The specific cause is hinted at in the detail of the message (see [Apple Technical note TN2250 advice on the -19011 issue](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32) for details)

In my case the error detail contained the phrase "Failed to load provision profile from:" after which I discovered that having spaces or special characters in the app OR the xcode scheme name can cause codesign verification fail.