# XCode 4, Invalid Signature (-19011)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, distribution, signature

I'm goin mad.

I'm using XCode 4 and finally i finished my app,and i was about to submit it to App Store,uploading to iTunes Connect. I tried to to Build for Archive but this warning showed up:

```
 Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
```

I've googled all day long,i've tried to renew all my certificates in Provisioning Center,i've even tried to upload it with Application loader but anything happened. Same error there too. I've tried to validate it through the Archive tab in Organizer but anything, this warning won't go away.

I've read some answers here, and even if the answers were a bit old, anything worked for me, i've tried to reinstall XCode too,i've tried to select the right profile on Build in Targets..

Thanks to anyone who will help me

edit:

When i try to start a new project and select "Build for Archive" and then Archive, the warning appears but i can still share the archive as ipa. I tried to copy all the files from my old project into the new one, build for archive, archived. But when i select "Share" as .ipa it shows an error

```
The operation couldn't be completed. No such files or directory.
```

May this be 'cause i added 2 frameworks to my project to work? Should i select something from Target,or Project? Also,i want to say that all my profiles are ok, certificates etc. I've tried to bypass the error -19011 by turning on NO "Validate built product".

EDIT2:
The -19011 doesn't show up anymore, but when i try to validate or submit,i got this error:

```
The archive is invalid. var/folders/*randomnumbers* app.ipa does not exist.
```

What am i supposed to do in this case? I've already read some of the answers but none worked.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved, thanks to the help of an Apple Technic Engineer, this way:

In targets, on Build Settings - Product name, I had the name of the app with spaces and special characters (`?` character). After changing that and changing the Bundle Name too, I solved all the problems I got with that.

Hope this will help someone, one day.

Comment: In my case I had an app name without spaces or special characters, but was using an XCode scheme that had a space

Comment: BTW I did not see this issue when using adhoc distribution profiles. It occurred when I switched to store distribution profiles. So this problem often comes at a stressful time, right before submit. Check for spaces when you see the -19011 error.

Answer (score 3):

You said you tried to "renew all my certificates in Provision Center". Are you certain you are:

1. Using a valid certificate. Have you imported the private key into your keychain?
2. Chosen the right provisioning profile + certificate combination for your "Release" or "Distribution" configuration?

It's possible that your Development configuration is correct, hence you could test on your device (if you have), but your Release configuration is wrong.

Go to "Build Settings" in XCode and verify that under "Release" or "Distribution", you chose your Distribution certificate (not development certificate) and the provisioning profile tied to it.

If that doesn't work, your problem is possibly related to 
[this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879473/how-to-fix-failed-codesign-verification-of-an-iphone-project)
Try reinstalling?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, yeah, i'm sure about the 2 points you asked. I tried to delete and to redo all my certificates + profiles. It seems impossibile that i get always that error. And the Release is fine, there's my Distribution certificate,it's set to automatic,but i changed manually with the Distribution certificate. And yes, i tried to reinstall everything, but anything,it seems useless!

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your distribution certificate is for the app store, and not for ad-hoc distribution?

Comment: yes it is. I've also noticed that if i turn "NO" "Validate built product" on Build Settings in target, the warning disappears, but when i go to validate the app from the archive, it says "app.ipa does not exist. And when i try to make the ipa it says "No such file or directory". FRUSTRATING

Answer (score 0):

From Product menu go to "Edit Schema", there find the Archive from the left sidebar and check which build configuration you are using for Archive. It should be distribution.

Another thing to check is which provision profile Distribution configuration is using, you can check this from projects Build Settings under Code Signing section.

Comment: The build configuration is "Release". For the Code Signing is everything alright. I've tried to archive a new empty project,and everything works fine,it even stores an ipa file. If i add the files plus 2 frameworks in the project, when i do "Archive" and then Share,it fails sayin "The operation couldn't be completed. No such files or directory". Pretty weird..Where am i failing?

Comment: Try removing the prov. profile and installing it back with a fresh copy from the provisioning portal, also make sure that the prov. profile has your developer certificate (you can check this by going to the modify page of the provision profile)

Comment: Okay, iTunesconnect does this weird thing, from itunesconnect go to modify prov. profile and add some devices or remove them, and save it.  Download it again. Make sure you change the selected devices. hope this would help.

Comment: You mean i have to build and archive when a device is connected?

Comment: No, from the provisioning portal, download the prov. profile again but this time, before downloading, try to edit it and so that it will be a fresh copy.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. i wrote  to apple,i'm waiting for them to answer

Answer (score 0):

After making sure my certificate and provisioning profile were correct for In-House deployment and making sure I didn't have any unwanted spaces or characters in the target names, what worked for me was to change my scheme from Debug to Release on the Run page.  Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Click Run -> Change Build Configuration to Release.