# How to set the Project and Target Build Settings for release?

Tags: xcode, settings, release

So, i finished my application and i'm stuck on the uploading part. I've tried to upload it with Application Loader and with Organizer (with the app archived) in XCode (i'm using XCode 4.0.2 SDK 4.3), but this warning \ error shows up in both the programs:

> Application failed codesign
>   verification. The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an
>   Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Now, all my provisioning profiles are ok, i did even make some new fresh certificates \ app id \ profiles. But the thing i don't understand it's how to set the Project Build Settings and the Target Build Settings. I'm really going crazy. I've googled a lot but i didn't find any solution to my problem. I've really tried ANYTHING.

Thanks to anyone who will help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4, Invalid Signature (-19011)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479257/xcode-4-invalid-signature-19011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, thanks to the help of an Apple Technic Engineer, that way:

In targets, on Build Settings - Product name, i had the name of the app with spaces and special characters ( ? char). After changing that,and changing the Bundle Name too, i solved all the problems i got with that.

Hope this will help someone, one day.