# Application failed code sign verification (NO entitlements)

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, code-signing

I'm getting this error after choosing my application record and signing identity in the "Submit..." wizard. I've check various things based on the answer on this site:

- I have a Distribution Certificate that expires in Jan 13, 2013.
- I create a Distribution Provisioning Profile for my app.
- Both the project and target have "iPhone Distribution: [company name]" set in Code Signing/Code Signing Identity/Release/Any iOS SDK.

  - The same identity was chosen in the "Submit..." wizard.
- Release is selected in the "Archive" scheme as Build Configuration.

I'm not using any entitlements (Xcode 4.2, without iCloud support)

```
Validate /Users/leonelgalan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/alma-dhzvecjmumvhvggrmlmqpnjblkoy/ArchiveIntermediates/alma/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/alma.app
    cd /Users/leonelgalan/Documents/workspace/ios/alma
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/leonelgalan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/alma-dhzvecjmumvhvggrmlmqpnjblkoy/ArchiveIntermediates/alma/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/alma.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/leonelgalan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/alma-dhzvecjmumvhvggrmlmqpnjblkoy/ArchiveIntermediates/alma/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/alma.app/alma
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/leonelgalan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/alma-dhzvecjmumvhvggrmlmqpnjblkoy/ArchiveIntermediates/alma/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/alma.app: valid on disk
/Users/leonelgalan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/alma-dhzvecjmumvhvggrmlmqpnjblkoy/ArchiveIntermediates/alma/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/alma.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879473/how-to-fix-failed-codesign-verification-of-an-iphone-project

Comment: Might want to check in apple developer that your cert wasn't pulled.  Mine was invalidated for no reason last night, so I had to make a new one.

Comment: Thank you both, I tried all suggested on the link magma suggested: re-running the installer, checking my xcodepj in a text editor, creating a new certificate, re-downloading the provisioning profile, but I still get the same error.

Comment: same problem for me... reading on apple dev forum it seems a technical problem!! Please update this post if you solve...

Comment: Anyone solved this issue? I've been wasting my time on that for 4 hours now, stupid apple!!!!Don'e everything from reinstalling xcode to revoking and renewing certificates and provisioning profiles.. I'm trying to AdHoc my app and it's god damn frustrating.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem on Apple’s part. See forum threads https://devforums.apple.com/thread/138186?start=0&tstart=0, https://devforums.apple.com/thread/138190?start=0&tstart=0 and https://devforums.apple.com/message/603758#603758

For reference radar://10697131.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the correct answer because it pointed to the correct spot. Certificates generated from Friday 13 (what a day!) to Early Monday 16 were incorrect. This was corrected Monday night. Just regenerate your certificates (both Dev and Distribution)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this part: warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011) by formatting my mac and only click "allow" instead of "always allow" when the keychain access was prompting me on using the enterprise certificate. i think its the allow/always allow part that fixed my problem. this is probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Scheme,
in the left window you will see Archive, press on it
in the build configuration press on release.
done!